# How to have two different inputs for command line?

Tags: java, command-line

I'm very new to java when using command line arguments.

I was wondering about how accept both a file input and another string argument.

Such as

```
java myprogram thanks.txt forhelp

    if(args.length < 1) {
        System.out.println("Error, usage: java ClassName inputfile");
    System.exit(1);
    }

    Scanner in = new Scanner(new FileInputStream(args[0]));
    String s = in.next();
```

is currently what I have but 
I can only seem to get the input file to pass in.

Comment: First of all that wont work coz you need something like java <ur-class> command line args

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/cmdLineArgs.html

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. There's no need to put the tag information in the subject. Tags are well designed here, and don't need help with things like `[JAVA]` in the subject. Please also review the [faq] for suggestions about how to ask questions in a way that will improve your chances of getting an answer. We'd like to help you, but if you don't show any effort to solve the problem yourself or what you've tried that isn't working, your question will probably be closed. You can [edit] your question to provide more information, though. Good luck! :-)

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the code:

```
    public static void main(String[] args){
     String file = args[0];
     String stringArg = args[1];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

command line arguments are `String`s.

The strings can be a filename, a port number etc - even a string.

It only depends on how you parse the command line arguments.

```
import java.io.*;

public class Norder {
    public static void main(String[] args ){
        if(args.length < 2) {
                   return;
                }else{
                   String filename = args[0]; //the first is always a filename
                   String str = args[1]; //the second argument is always a string
                   BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));
                   //do something with the reader object
                   br.close();
                }             
        }
}
```